# Proving any bounded sequence in $R^m$ has a limit point and thus converges.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

So I believe I need to develop some sort of a similar argument to the theorem which states :

*If $S$ is an infinite subset of $R^m$ then S has a cluster point.

Which I proved :

We prove that if $S$ is an infinite subset of a compact set $C$ (e.g. a large closed ball which is compact by the Heine-Borel theorem), then $S$ has a cluster point. If this were not the case, then every point $p ∈ C$ would have an open neighborhood $N_p$ about $p$ which contained only a finite number of points of $S$. The collection of all these sets, namely that $N_p$ such that $p∈C$ is an open covering of $C$ and must have a finite sub-cover $n_p$ for $C$. But this implies that $S$ is finite which is absurd.
Since We assumed S is infinite at the beginning, S has a cluster point.*

**Now I am trying to use this approach to prove that any bounded sequence in $R^m$ has a limit point and thus converges**

Let the points of this sequence be contained in a set $S$. Since S is a subset of some compact set $C$, it openly covered by a finite number of open coverings. These open coverings (finite number of ) cover $S$ too. But If S doesn't converge coverings wouldn't be finite.

That's where I could have came so far. What should I do next?
I also have some questions :

1)If this set $S$ a limit point would that limit point be on the boundary of $S$? I didn't understand what $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ stand for. Some people say I understood it wrong, I think $\liminf{a_n}$ is the same as $inf(S)$ where $S$ is the set formed by the points of $a_n$. Is this correct? If it is incorrect, can someone explain to me?

2) How would i prove this more mathematically?

Comment: The sequence $x_n = (-1)^n$ is bounded, but does not converge

Comment: A bounded _monotone_ sequence, however, does always converge

Comment: Your question is difficult to address fully in the format of Math.SE for a couple of reasons: 1. The title question ("a bounded sequence...converges") is not correct as stated; 2. the post contains multiple auxiliary questions, and 3. usages of language that suggest conceptual misunderstandings (e.g., "covered by a finite number of open coverings"). (Your understanding of $\liminf$ is not correct, incidentally; if $a_{n} = (-1)^{n}/n$, then $\inf a_{n} = -1$ while $\liminf a_{n} = 0$.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang instead of telling me all of that you could have edited. It was a mistake unpurposely done lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence $x_n = (-1)^n$ is bounded and does not converge. However, it is a well known result (Bolzano-Weierstrass) that every bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ has a convergent subsequence. I will try to help you with your other question.

Consider $a_n = n$. Then the set $S$ you describe is in fact the natural numbers, $\mathbb{N}$. Then $\inf\{\Bbb{N}\} = 1$. But $\liminf a_n = \infty$. One nice way to understand this is to consider $S_1 = \emptyset$, and $S_n = \cup_{i=1}^{n-1} \{a_n\}$. Now consider the sequence $b_n = \inf\{S\setminus S_n\}$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n = \liminf a_n$ That is we start by finding the infimum of the set $S$ then we find the infimum of the sequence resulting from removing the first term. Then the second. We continue in this way to find the $\liminf$.

Here I will leave the usual definition of limit inferior.
$\liminf a_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}\inf\{a_m|m\ge n\}$